# Get GPS when Android Intent is Started

Tags: java, android, gps, location, locationmanager

I thought this would be super easy - but this is taking waaaay longer than it should.

I'm simply trying to get the GPS coordinates to go to the logcat, that's literally it.

The intent fires fine. The "Intent Fired" message appears every time. The application just refuses to go to the location changed event.

If someone could take a look and let me know where I'm failing, it would be super appreciated.

```
public class MyReceiver extends IntentService implements LocationListener {
private LocationManager locationManager;
public MyReceiver() {
    super("MyReceiver");
}

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("DebugMe", "Intent Fired");
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    String lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    String lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    Log.i("DebugMe", lat + " " + lon);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("DebugMe ", "Disabled");
}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("DebugMe","Enabled");
}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("DebugMe","Status");
}
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the location manager works asynchronously, and `IntentService` is implemented in such a way, that when `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` returns, the service stops itself. That means it's destroyed before any location can be provided to your `onLocationChanged(location location)` method. If you want to use `IntentService` you need to block the `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` method from returning before you have your location, or use a standard `Service` and execute `stopSelf` when you obtain a `Location` object.

```
public class MyReceiver extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        onHandleIntent(intent);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("DebugMe", "Intent Fired");
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        String lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        Log.i("DebugMe", lat + " " + lon);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        // this is where you stop the service
        stopSelf();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("DebugMe ", "Disabled");
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("DebugMe", "Enabled");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("DebugMe", "Status");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this implementation won't run in a separate thread as default, as an IntentService would.

Comment: "use a standard Service an execute stopSelf when you obtain a Location object." -- IMHO, this is the much better approach.

Comment: Well thank god I asked - I never would of figured that out on my own. The reason why Im using an intent service is because this application needs to be able to take commands from adb and this solution allows me to do "adb shell am startservice ... " from a laptop... Is there another way to implement a GPS lookup from the adb cmd line?

Comment: Sure there is, I encourage you to look up the implementation of IntentService. Basically what it is, is a specialized version of Service that handles a single intent in a different thread and stops itself. You can start a standard service with adb just the same. As for the implementation, check out the answer in a minute.

Comment: Worked like a charm - thank you very very much for the help.

Comment: Related side question relating to getting the GPS - Is there a difference between using LocationRequest and Criteria? It seems like everyone uses one or the other, but I haven't seen a comparison of the two.